# PyQt4 - How to shrink the layout on Mac OSX?

Tags: python, macos, qt, layout, pyqt

For the same PyQt4 code, the layout looks quite equivalent on Linux and Windows. But with MacOSX, we see that :

- the elements seems to take a little more space (mostly bt_bookmark which doesn't shrink to the expected size)
- a lot of space is used between the elements (that's the most annoying thing)

How could it be shrink to the minimum? Is there a margin policy that we need to set globally or anything else?

Here is the code used for the test case :

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class GUI(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()

        vbox_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        for i in range(4):
            hbox_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
            bt_bookmark = QtGui.QPushButton()
            bt_bookmark.setGeometry(0, 0, 15, 15)
            bt_bookmark.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("./bookmark_on.png"))
            hbox_layout.addWidget(bt_bookmark)
            hbox_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton("Button1"))
            hbox_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Some text here."))
            hbox_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton("Button2"))
            hbox_layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton("Button3"))
            vbox_layout.addLayout(hbox_layout)

        self.setLayout(vbox_layout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Test Layout")
        self.show()
        self.resize_window_to_minimum()

    def resize_window_to_minimum(self):
        # http://stackoverflow.com/a/28667119/446302
        def _func_to_call():
            self.resize(self.minimumSizeHint())
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(500, _func_to_call)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    gui = GUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the captures :

[image: On Ubuntu 14.04]

[image: On OSX 10.10.3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the space between the widgets you can use `QBoxLayout.setSpacing()`.

About the size of the buttons, you could try to adjust it by setting the margin or padding with style sheets.

Personally I would set the stretch of the bt_bookmark to 0 (`hbox_layout.addWidget(bt_bookmark, stretch=0)`) and the stretch factor of the other buttons to 1. This way the button bt_bookmark doesn't grow when the window is resized.

Comment: Thanks. I could solve it with : `self.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)` , `vbox_layout.setSpacing(0)` and `vbox_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`